# How do I upload a new version of my project to SVN (eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a Java project in an SVN server. I created a whole new version of it and now I want to "commit" but keep the previous version on the server. I'm not allowed to use branches on this project. So I've changed the new project's name to `projectName_improved`. I created a new folder for the project on the server. Now I want to upload `projectName_improved` to the new folder. I'm using eclipse (+SVN plugin). How do I technically do it (without branching)?

**EDIT:** The plugin I'm using is [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- In Eclipse, go to the SVN Repositories perspective.

[image: SVN Repositories]

- Right click on the folder in which you want to put the new (improved) project.

[image: right click on the destination folder]

- import (to import a project to the server).

[image: import window]

- Browse...
- Find the project on your computer. OK. OK. That's it. The new (improved) project is being uploaded to the server. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Not a Java person myself, but from experience it sounds like you need to either;

A. Create a new repository on the SVN server.
or B. Simply ADD the new folder in the existing repository and then in eclipse you should be able to commit.

I don't think there is anything in the eclipse plug-in itself that alows you to ADD new folders, you have to do that from the OS, or using an app like RapidSVN.

When I say ADD i mean that you can right click on the folder in win explorer and under SVN you can click the Add command.  I am using tortoisesvn.... it will also add icons to your folders to let you know what needs to be committed.

- http://tortoisesvn.net/
- http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect from the svn first `(eclipse -> team menu -> disconnect)` which will delete the existing svn info(say yes when it asks) and then again from the `team menu share project- > follow on screen guiding` into the svn repo (chosing the place you want to put it in. probably trunk). is this not working?